# Angular2 - binding to formControl when using Select2 multiple select

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to use Select2 in my Angular2 application. I could print out my selection when I choose the options but having a problem to bind the selected options to my angular form control.

This is my html:

```
<select id="fields" class="form-control fields-select" multiple="multiple" 
        formControlName="branchCode">
  <option *ngFor="let field of _availableFields" [value]="field">{{field}}
  </option>
</select>
```

This is my ts file:

```
private _availableFields: Array<any> = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'];
private _selectedFields: Array<string> = [];

export class AppComponent{
    editForm : new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      branchCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
 });
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
   jQuery('.fields-select').select2();
   jQuery('.fields-select').on('change',
      (e) => 
         this._selectedFields = jQuery(e.target).val();
         console.log(this._selectedFields);
   );
};
```

I got my selection in var this._selectedFields.
How could I bind my selected value in this._selectedFields to my formControl 'branchCode'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using `jQuery select2` library with angular is a nice idea, you should instead check out [ng2-select](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/) which is an select2 like library for angular and you will not run into these problems.